Replacing Cell Reference With INDIRECT+ROW
I have a formula that finds the index of the first non-empty cell in a specified range:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(H1,0,0,10,1)="",0,0),0)
The formula works as expected. However, I want to get rid of using cell addresses directly. So, I was planning to use INDIRECT combined with ADDRESS but it doesn't work:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),0,0,10,1)="",0,0),0)
I did some more tests and found that the formula somehow doesn't work with ROW:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()),0,0,10,1)="",0,0),0)
But if to "hardcode" the cell address, the formula works:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT("H1"),0,0,10,1)="",0,0),0)
So, the question is: How to overcome that problem?
P.S.: Non-array formula is preferred.
P.S.2: I'm using Excel 2019.





What does =OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),0,0,10,1) return for you? (I cannot reproduce your problem, all your formulas work on my computer. but my excel is Office365).

It always returns 5. Checked it with different combinations of values in the column H.

I understood: It returns the value in the first cell of the created range.

The array formula is not preferred. Anyway, I cannot figure out why the formula doesn't work with ROW.

What about this =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+10,COLUMN()+1))? does that return a range on your excel?

It also returns the first value in the range.

I've found the solution: Looks like ROW and COLUMN return arrays. So, adding CHOOSE functions to ROW and COLUMN solves the problem:=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CHOOSE(1,ROW()),CHOOSE(1,COLUMN())+1)),0,0,10,1)="",,),0)


OFFSET INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile, therefore using this is not advisable if you can accomplish the same elseway:
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($1:$1048576,ROW(),COLUMN()+1):INDEX($1:$1048576,ROW()+10,COLUMN()+1)="",0)
I think this requires being entered with ctrl+shift+enter in Excel 2019.


It returns an empty value. Also, the array formula is not preferred.

That's incorrect. Added a screenshot.

Strangely enough, but this time it worked.

Why would you prefer a volatile function (that recalculates if any of the cells in the file are changed) over an array formula?

I can also confirm that this works in Excel 2019 when entered as CSE (ctrl+shift+enter); also we could limit $1048576 to a suitable value (for example $500) depending on the max rows in your data set.

@P.b, because I often forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when updating formulae. And since I'm developing a workbook that will be used by other users too, I think they will encounter the same issue.

@nkalvi Narrowing the index range does not matter for calculation. INDEX by itself doesn't calculate. It's used to create an intersection or a from to range based on the calculation of the row/column arguments). INDEX(A:A,1) is the same as INDEX(A1:A999,1)

I wonder if other users like the volatile functions..

@P.b, that depends on the complexity of a workbook. My current workbook works fast, so  volatile functions definitely beat Ctrl+Shift+Enter in my case.

I appreciate you pointing this out @P.b - thank you! Yes, I'm aware of it; it is just in case one is lazy (like I'm, often :)  to lookup the max row number for a quick calculation of this sort.

Could you try this in Excel 2019? (I don't have it):
=MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,1,10,1)="",0)



Have just tried. The formula throws an error.

You're right; just installed Excel 2019 to figure out why. OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1,10,1) returns an array under Microsoft 365 and returns the first value under Excel 2019 (entering as a CSE does't make a difference.)

Yeah… It's one of the problems that different Excel versions behave differently and have different set of built-in functions.

Agree. I started working with Excel formulas (that is beyond simple sums etc.) only a few months ago on Mac Office 365; slowly noticing difference in functionality between Mac/Windows/2016/2019…
